# How do I keep track of parsing progress of large files in StAX?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'm processing large (1TB) XML files using the StAX API. Let's assume we have a loop handling some elements:

```
XMLInputFactory fac = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
 XMLStreamReader reader = fac.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
   while (true) {
       if (reader.nextTag() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT){
            // handle contents
       }
}
```

How do I keep track of overall progress within the large XML file? Fetching the offset from reader works fine for smaller files:

```
int offset = reader.getLocation().getCharacterOffset();
```

but being an Integer offset, it'll probably only work for files up to 2GB...

Comment: is that a single 1TB xml file?

Comment: Yup. Don't have any control over this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `FilterReader` should work.

```
class ProgressCounter extends FilterReader {
    long progress = 0;

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        progress += n;
        return super.skip(n);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int red = super.read(cbuf, off, len);
        progress += red;
        return red;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int red = super.read();
        progress += red;
        return red;
    }

    public ProgressCounter(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    public long getProgress () {
        return progress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the Stax API can't give you a `long` offset.

As a workaround you could create a custom `java.io.FilterReader` class which overrides `read()`  and `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` to increment a `long` offset.

You would pass this reader to the `XMLInputFactory`. 
The handler loop can then get the offset information directly from the reader.

You could also do this on the byte-level reading using a `FilterInputStream`, counting the byte offset instead of character offset. That would allow for a exact progress calculation given the file size.