# How to getProgress of large files using XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, xmlstreamreader

I am using below code to read large xml file (in GBs) in hadoop RecordReader using XMLStreamReader

```
public class RecordReader {
   int progressCouunt = 0;
   public RecordReader() {
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    FSDataInputStream fdDataInputStream = fs.open(file); //hdfs file
    try {
          reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(fdDataInputStream);
    } catch (XMLStreamException exception) {
           throw new RuntimeException("XMLStreamException exception : ", exception);
    }
   }
   @Override
  public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     return progressCouunt; 
   }
}
```

My question is how to get reading progress of the file with XMLStreamReader as it does not provide any start or end position to calculate the progress percentage. 
I have refered to [How do I keep track of parsing progress of large files in StAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724494/how-do-i-keep-track-of-parsing-progress-of-large-files-in-stax), but cannot user filterReader.
Please help me here.

Comment: Do you know the full length of the stream?

Comment: no, with stax it is not possible as it uses pull streaming so cannot get whole file size.

Comment: I mean, from somewhere else. Because if there is no way for you to determine the total length of your data **before** you start streaming it, there is no way for you to track progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the `InputStream` by extending `FilterInputStream`.

```
public interface InputStreamListener {
    void onBytesRead(long totalBytes);
}

public class PublishingInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    private final InputStreamListener;
    private long totalBytes = 0;

    public PublishingInputStream(InputStream in, InputStreamListener listener) {
       super(in);
       this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b) {
       int count = super.read(b);
       this.totalBytes += count;
       this.listener.onBytesRead(totalBytes);
    }

    // TODO: override the other read() methods
}
```

Usage

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
InputStream in = fs.open(file);
final long fileSize = someHadoopService.getFileLength(file);
InputStremListener listener = new InputStreamListener() {
    public void onBytesRead(long totalBytes) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Read %s of %s bytes", totalBytes, fileSize));
    }
};
InputStream publishingIn = new PublishingInputStream(in, listener);
try {
    reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(publishingIn);
    // etc
```

Comment: actually I am using org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader and need to read progress inside it. Could you please help me here.

Comment: So, update the progress in the custom `InputStreamListener `. To get a precentage you'll need to know the total bytes. `InputStream.available()` does NOT guarantee to return the total bytes (it returns the total number that can be read without blocking). But you may find that this method works (depending on the InputStream implementation)

Comment: I have tried using with `.available()` method but here total read bytes and available bytes are always same.